# Detect number of dimensions of numpy array (not shape)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

Getting the shape of two different numpy arrays returns tuples

```
a.shape
Out[131]: (3,)

A.shape
Out[132]: (3, 3)
```

Based on the tuples, one is a one-dimensional array (number of dimensions = 1), the other is 2d. How can I detect number of dimensions similar to how `type(A)` will tell me one of them is a `numpy.ndarray`? should I just use `len(a.shape)`?

Comment: `len(a.shape)` is fine.  `a.ndim` also.  I doubt if it makes much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [numpy.ndarray.ndim](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html). So

```
a.ndim # gives 1
```

and

```
A.ndim # gives 2
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dims'`